# getline() function in c++ takes 1 less input

Tags: c++, string, getline

```
int main() 
{
int n;
cin>>n;
string str1[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    getline(cin,str1[i]);
return 0;
}
```

I wrote a code to input n strings but the code takes only (n-1) strings as input.
What is the reason for this?

Comment: A related question provides the fix. The related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction. The fix: add `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')` after `cin>>n;`.

Comment: @Robᵩ thanks, solved my problem.

Comment: [OT] `string str1[n];` is a variable length array and not standard.  You can change it to `std::vector<std::string> str1(n);`

Comment: @NathanOliver - I'm new to this. Can you please explain `string str1[n];` should not be used. It works perfectly (after correcting the code that is)

Comment: @GibreelAbdullah it is not standard, meaning the C++ standard does not included it in the features of C++.  Some compilers like your allow it as a compiler extension since it is allowed in C99.  The problem with using them in C++ is if you give someone else your code it might not compile as you are using something that isn't guaranteed to exist.  IT is better to use a vector as vectors are part of the standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for` loop does run for `n` iterations, and `getline` does read in `n` lines. Consider this input:

```
2
First
Second
```

In that input there are three (not two!) lines: `2\n`, `First\n`, and `Second\n`.

Your formatted input (`cin>>n`) reads *part* of the first line: `2`. Then the loop runs twice, reading in this data: `\n` and `First\n`. The third and final line (`Second\n`) is never read.

The solution is to read the `\n` from the first line before the loop begins. This can be accomplished various ways. Here is one:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')
```